# What modifications/corrections are made by $f(R)$ gravity model on Morris-Thorne wormhole metric?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, metric-tensor, wormholes, modified-gravity

What modifications/corrections are made by the $f(R)$ gravity model on the Morris-Thorne wormhole metric? Specifically, how does the physics associated with the metric change in $f(R)$ gravity compare to the General Theory of Relativity?